# is there a way to get the smtpaddress for an mapifolder or outlook interop folder given the entryid (or storeid)

Tags: outlook

if i have the storeid for a mapifolder, selected through the folderpicker from the outlook interop libraries, is there a way for me to get the smtpaddress for that folder?

i know it's in the extended properties, but i was hoping to do it without any heavy parsing or ldap querying.

the reason i need the smtpaddress is in order to connect to the folder via EWS - i'm currently trying to replace our references to outlook interop with exchange web services, and this has become a sticking point, since many of our users have delegate access to mailboxes that don't belong to them

Comment: In general, folders do not have SMTP addresses. Do you mean the folder id?

Comment: i don't - i mean the smtpaddress of the owner of the mailbox the folder is in.  in order to take the entryid property of the mapifolder and convert it to the exchange web service store id, i need to provide the smtpaddress of the owner of the mailbox.

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.idformat(v=exchg.80).aspx) is the enum for the idformat. 

so that i can convert as [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb856559(v=exchg.140).aspx)

Comment: reached the edit limit of the previous comment [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184600.aspx) is what i wanted to do, but when i use the folderpicker to select a folder in another user's mailbox (which i have access to), i get nothing back for the account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the mailbox owner, you can either try to read the `MAPIFolder.Store` property to get to the parent store, then read the `PR_MAILBOX_OWNER_ENTRYID` property (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x661B0102"`) using `Store.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`. You can then use the store owner entry id to call `Namespace.GetAddressEntryFromID`. Once you have the `AddressEntry` object, you can use `AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress`.

Note that `PR_MAILBOX_OWNER_ENTRYID` property is only available in the online stores. You might want to use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) and its [RDOExchangeMailboxStore](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm#RDOExchangeMailboxStore).Owner.SmtpAddress property. `RDOExchangeMailboxStore` can be retrieved using `RDOSession.GetRDOObjectfromOutlookObject(Store)` or using `RDOSession.GetStoreFromID`.

Comment: this worked like a charm - the only thing id add is that GetProperty returns a byte(), and converting it to string with system.text.encoding doesn't work as expected.  rather, you need to use PropertyAccessor.BinaryToString

Comment: Do not get it to work :( i get back the byte array, but i am not able to convert it to something meaningful

Comment: Use PropertyAccessor.BinaryToString

Comment: What do you mean by "property is only available in the online stores". I have a problem with reading  PR_MAILBOX_OWNER_ENTRYID from the Store properties. It responds with "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x661B0102" is unknown or cannot be found.

Comment: That is exactly what I mean - you will be able to successfully retrieve that property from a store only if the cached mode is turned off.  Otherwise you get the error you are getting.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing was that the stores are in fact cached in my setup. So assuming that I need to work with cached stores and that using redemption is sadly not an option, is there a way to access the mailbox differently? I managed to get it work using LDAP based on this post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeamsgdev/2012/12/07/outlook-how-to-determine-the-owner-of-an-item-including-an-item-from-a-shared-folder/. However I would prefer to avoid requests to Active Directory. I noticed in some other thread, you mentioned that using profiles via MAPI is also an option. Any more details? Thx

Comment: If using Redemption is not an option, you can only do it using Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) -the data is stored in the profile section.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Comment: I tried as described there but `GetProperty(PR_MAILBOX_OWNER_ENTRYID)` gets  an exception `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`... Any ideas on why?

Comment: @Eñaut - as noted above, PR_MAILBOX_OWNER_ENTRYID is only available if the store is *not* cached. You can also try to parse the store entry id. extract the EX address, then use it to create a GAL entry id.

Comment: I see, thank you. But as store is cached can I get his entryID? Do you mean storeID?

Comment: Yes, the store entry id - take a look at it in OutlookSpy: click IMsgStore button, select PR_ENTRYID or PR_STORE_ENTRYID property, see the "Symb" edit box.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's years later (sorry), but I needed get SMTP addresses for a bunch of mailboxes, and the accepted answer didn't work (because I've got offline stores) so I did the parsing.

```cs
public static bool TryGetSmtpAddress(MAPIFolder folder, out string smtpAddress)
{
    smtpAddress = default;

    var storeId = HexToBytes(folder.StoreID);

    // check it's a store entry id
    if (BitConverter.ToUInt64(storeId, 4) != 0x1A10E50510BBA138UL
        || BitConverter.ToUInt64(storeId, 12) != 0xC2562A2B0008BBA1UL) { return false; }

    var indexDn = Array.IndexOf(storeId, (byte)0x00, 60) + 1;
    var indexV3Block = Array.IndexOf(storeId, (byte)0x00, indexDn) + 1;

    // check it's a V3 entry id (with SMTP address)
    if (BitConverter.ToUInt32(storeId, indexV3Block) != 0xF43246E9UL) { return false; }

    var offsetSmtpAddress = BitConverter.ToUInt32(storeId, indexV3Block + 12);

    smtpAddress = BytesToUnicode(storeId, indexV3Block + (int)offsetSmtpAddress);
    return true;
}

private static byte[] HexToBytes(string input)
{
    var bytesLength = input.Length / 2;
    var bytes = new byte[bytesLength];
    for (var i = 0; i < bytesLength; i++) { bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(input.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16); }
    return bytes;
}

private static string BytesToUnicode(byte[] value, int startIndex)
{
    var charsLength = (value.Length - startIndex) / 2;
    var chars = new char[charsLength];
    for (var i = 0; i < charsLength; i++)
    {
        var c = chars[i] = BitConverter.ToChar(value, startIndex + i * 2);
        if (c == '\0') { return new String(chars, 0, i); }
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NZTony's answer in VB.net:

```
Public Sub test()
        Dim smtpAddress As String
        Dim selectedItem As Outlook.Folder
        smtpAddress = ""
        TryGetSmtpAddress(Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).Parent, smtpAddress)
End Sub

Public Shared Function TryGetSmtpAddress(ByVal folder As MAPIFolder, ByRef smtpAddress As String) As Boolean
        smtpAddress = "default"
        Dim storeId = HexToBytes(folder.StoreID)

        If BitConverter.ToUInt64(storeId, 4) <> &H1A10E50510BBA138UL OrElse BitConverter.ToUInt64(storeId, 12) <> &HC2562A2B0008BBA1UL Then
            Return False
        End If

        Dim indexDn = Array.IndexOf(storeId, CByte(&H0), 60) + 1
        Dim indexV3Block = Array.IndexOf(storeId, CByte(&H0), indexDn) + 1

        If BitConverter.ToUInt32(storeId, indexV3Block) <> &HF43246E9UL Then
            Return False
        End If

        Dim offsetSmtpAddress = BitConverter.ToUInt32(storeId, indexV3Block + 12)
        smtpAddress = BytesToUnicode(storeId, indexV3Block + CInt(offsetSmtpAddress))
        Return True
End Function

    Private Shared Function HexToBytes(ByVal input As String) As Byte()
        Dim bytesLength = input.Length / 2
        Dim bytes = New Byte(bytesLength - 1) {}

        For i = 0 To bytesLength - 1
            bytes(i) = Convert.ToByte(input.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16)
        Next

        Return bytes
End Function

    Private Shared Function BytesToUnicode(ByVal value As Byte(), ByVal startIndex As Integer) As String
        Dim charsLength = (value.Length - startIndex) / 2
        Dim chars = New Char(charsLength - 1) {}

        For i = 0 To charsLength - 1
            Dim c = CSharpImpl.__Assign(chars(i), BitConverter.ToChar(value, startIndex + i * 2))
            If c = vbNullChar Then
                Return New String(chars, 0, i)
            End If
        Next

        Return New String(chars)
End Function

Private Class CSharpImpl
        <Obsolete("Please refactor calling code to use normal Visual Basic assignment")>
        Shared Function __Assign(Of T)(ByRef target As T, value As T) As T
            target = value
            Return value
        End Function
End Class
```